# Two tool tip for two different charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I have two charts line and scatter together. I want two different tool tip for two different graphs. I have set for one but I couldn't do for another. Please help me out.

**Code**

```
 this.chart = new Chart({
 tooltip: {  
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            shared: true,
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'BG',
            color: '#FA8686',
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
            data: [[1571715050000, 95],[1571729415000, 115]]
          },
          {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Insulin',
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
            data: [{x:1571715050000, y:30, tool:85},{x:1577729415005, y:30, tool:90}],
          }]
})
```

**My output for scatter**

[image: O/P]

But I want only the tool value  to be in the tool tip of the scatter. Is there is any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the tooltip on a series level:

```
series: [{
        ...,
        tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            pointFormat: '{point.x}'
        },
    },
    {
        ...,
        tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            pointFormat: '{point.y}'
        },
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/doqxygb9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.tooltip.pointFormat